# Cannot use message.guild.me.displayColor in code files in the commands folder

Tags: discord, discord.js

the message.guild.me.displayColor , which is used to set the color of the embed as the bot's highest role's color, does not work in the files in the commands folder. I have tried using:

```
let color = message.guild.me.displayColor
```

But that doesnt seem to work, however message.guild.me.displayColor works only in the index(main) file. Maybe it's the way I included the files? if so, you can review how I included those files

```
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

I would appreciate it if  someone helps me out

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No i don't get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your way of reading the files looks a little off to me, I believe that it's not the issue here. *Note: If your commands are not executed, try to replace it with this. You can easily check if your commands are working or not with a simple `console.log("works")`.*

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
};
```

Now to your actual question. Your way of setting the color doesn't work because [`displayColor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayColor) returns the color in base 10. To use the highes role color in an embed you need to use [`displayHexColor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayHexColor) as embeds cannot use base 10 colors.

```
let color = message.guild.me.displayHexColor;
```